# HTTPSからCSSファイルを読み込めない: Get https://url/mypath/file.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: http, tomcat, https

### 現状のソースコード

**MyFile.html**

```
<link href="./mypath/file.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

### 発生している問題

`http://localhost:8080/`の時に問題なく動いたが、`https://url/`の時に

```
Get https://url/mypath/file.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

のエラーが発生しています。

ただし`https://url/mypath/file.css`へそのままアクセスすると、`file.css`の確認はできます。今までHTTPで問題なく動いているものですので、ファイルが存在しないの問題はないです。

### 環境

- Windows
- Tomcat 8.5.32

どなたか解決できますか？お願いします。

Comment: curlや`Invoke-WebRequest`などで当該のURLを呼び出したときに(CSS自体は返って来ているということでしょうが)ステータスコード200が正しく返って来ていますか？

Comment: はい、
<https://url/mypath/>でアクセスの時に
<https://url/mypath/>　のステータスは200で
<https://url/mypath/file.css>のステータスは404です。

Comment: ん？「はい」なんですか？404が返ってきてしまっているんですか？(404なのであればそれが問題としかいいようがないような)